# 25 machine network advice needed

Tags: networking

I need to connect 25 computers together in a school.

Can I use just the one router, one switch with many ports, and a modem for internet connection? or is it best to use a couple of routers for security if that has any valid point?

Security: does a router normally include security software protecting the whole networks?

Is it best to use a server or dedicate a node to play its role as a server which then gives all other computers access to software, has security etc?

Comment: Please hire a consultant...  I'm not sure of your location, but where I am, schools have to follow certain regulatory requirements related to IT.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a well-formulated question.  It really does lead to too many tangents, and opens itself up to a lot more questions than it will ever answer.

Without knowing the requirements for security, reliability, bandwidth, etc... you could be talking about a huge number of possible answers.  It's like telling a librarian you need a book... and not offering any information about your needs in that book.  (fiction? reference? subject? etc...)

In short: yes, you can setup a network with a single switch, and a single router, and it may fit all your needs.  Probably not... but it might.

If this is not your full-time-job, you probably should consider talking with a consultant who does this for a living.  There are many MANY things that should to be considered.  (for liability reasons, as well as simply wanting to provide features)

The most important question to answer first is: "What exactly do you want to achieve?"  You cannot reliably/accurately hit a target that keeps changing.  Come up with a list of specific things you wish to provide.  And by specific, I mean things like "Access websites on the Internet" or "Share files" or "Provide Email".  You can also get more detailed things like "Access 3 specific websites on the internet" rather than a general "Access the Internet".  (the more specific you can be, the better)

Questions about security should first be thought in terms of "protect what/who from what/who".  i.e. protect students from visiting websites with questionable content?  protect outside hackers from gaining access to your systems? etc...

Maintaining the systems should also be a consideration.  After you turn them on, who will be "mr-fixit?"  Do you plan on growing?  Do you need to share resources?  (files/printers/???)  Do you wish to require usernames/passwords to access certain resources? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need to do. If you just create an IT classroom with 25 PCs you can simply make the network by connecting them with the switch.

If you need to scatter the PCs to the departments (or something like that) it is a good idea to create a subnet for each dept. and implement security measures accordingly.

Routers, even those low-end ones, usually come with a filter implementation which quality is according to the cost :)

But your question is too general to say something more useful. For example, you maybe don't even need any server.

Comment: Yes I am very vague. The only useful thing I can say is that the school would run 25 computers to provide facilties for students whereby they conducts online language exams in real time.  The internet needs to be fast, each machine for example should have at least 5mb connection to enable it to be efficient and quick enough.  security maybe a server is not needed but instead using a standalone pc to act as a server and ghost copying everything over the rest of the pcs. and reliability needs to be an issue here as exams cannot be interrupted.